# Eclipse shows red lines at mouse pointer

Tags: eclipse, pointers, lines

Since I have re-installed my computer, there is a strange phenomena using Eclipse (both JAVA and C/C++).

The moment I press control+shift+s, two red lines appear near my mouse pointer.
Image of the red lines:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/92764732@N03/8431379591/

When I look in the settings-> keys, the control+shift+s is mapped to save all.
However, it does not save all, and only shows the red lines.

Defaulting the keys mapping does not work, I have tried this.

Does anyone has any idea on what these red lines mean, and how to get rid of them?!

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Well great, turned out it wasn't Eclipse after all.

Control+Shift+S is a shortcut from Mouse without borders (great tool by the way)!

So, fixed that one, on to saving a lot of files in one press :)